# if the element is displayed then the test failed

Tags: protractor

I need a way to make the test fail with specific message. For example if the element isDisplayed() i want the test to fail

```
element(myElement).isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
  if (result) {
  //test fail
  }
else {
 //do something else
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jasmine for reporting then you can override custom error message by implementing custom matchers for expect statements.
Note: we can directly pass custom error message  as an additional parameter for in expect statements but that is not documented feature so may not be supported in future.It is better approach to implement it as custom matcher.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jasmine's [`done.fail`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction#section-58):

```
it('your test', (done) => {
  element(myElement).isDisplayed().then((result) => {
    if (result) {
      done.fail('a custom error message');
    }
    //do something else
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the failure message as an extra parameter to jasmine matchers for every failure.Look at below example.

```
expect(element(myElement).isDisplayed()).toBe(true,'myElement is not displayed in the page.')
```

Here the message `myElement is not displayed on the page.` will be displayed in console/reporter if the above expect statement fails.